# How to prompt user to save an automated Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, automation, savefiledialog

I have searched and nothing that I have found hits directly on what I am looking for (or maybe my searches have not hit on the combo of words).

In C# I have created an Excel sheet, using Interop.Excel, in which I insert some data and create a chart. This all works fine when I do a xlWorkBook.SaveAs.

What I want to do is prompt the user to put the automated workbook somewhere with thier  own file name. I have tried (http://p2p.wrox.com/vb-how/63900-disabling-second-excel-save-prompt.html) where he basically does a new SaveFileDialog then if its == OK he builds his Excel sheet then he says that his workbook.SaveAs(FilePathFromSaveAsDialog) causes a prompt. When I try it, I get the "Showing modal dialog box when application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation" error.
I would paste all my code but it is on a seperate system, however the just of it is:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Office 

//....then on click of link button....

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorbook;
Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks;
Excel.Sheets xlSheets;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
xlWorkBook = xlWorbooks.Add(misValue);
xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.get_Item(1);

//....Now I fill my Excel sheet data and make my chart >>> then I close like below...

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;

//HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO EITHER PASS THE PATH AND FILE NAME FROM USER OR USE A PROMPT
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Test.xls", Excel.XFileFormat.XlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);    
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

//finally I release all my objects via Marshal.ReleaseComObject then GC.Collect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the file stored somewhere after you save it you can use Response.

Here's an example:

```
  const string fName = @"C:\Test.xls";
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fName);
  long sz = fi.Length;

  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(fName);
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}",System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName)));
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sz.ToString("F0"));
  Response.TransmitFile(fName);
  Response.End();
```

This should prompt the user where they want to store the file on their machine.

Comment: Thnx...I have done the Response.AddHeader thing in the past when I just RenderControl on a datagrid and then the prompt comes up. But in this scenario I do not want to have to save the file on their machine, or my server for that matter, and then go get it again. I would like to do one output.

Comment: @Kevin You can use for example Response.BinaryWrite to pass the file as a byte array to the user, without saving it to your server. If that is an option for you.

Comment: I have not used BinaryWrite before so I will have to look into it. My chief concern is the unknown (even though this would happen quickly in code), like if the user changed the file name, their system went down, they are on a thin client and drives may be mapped differently, the load/conflict it may create if multiple users do this at once, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is the easy way. :-)

```
myFilename = xlapp.GetSaveAsFilename
xlWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=myFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, it seems crazy, but worked.

`xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveExcel(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);//import method`

`internal object saveExcel()//method`

```
    {

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();// Create save the CSV
        sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.xls";// filters for text files only
        sfd.DefaultExt = "xls";
        sfd.AddExtension = true;
        sfd.FileName = "AutodeskScripts.xls";
        sfd.Title = "Save Excel File";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return sfd.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```