# Download file instead Save As file [Micosoft.Interop] C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, httpresponse, excel-interop

I have success create excel file using interop from dataset. But I create save as using pat hardcode Url. I want make saveAs path Url to be download file showing popup windows using `Response.Bufer = true;`

```
....
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
....
```

How to using poup save windows location?

Comment: Try commenting out the `SaveAs` line, if you call `xlWorkBook.Close()` it should automatically open a Dialog asking to save as first.

Comment: Not work. this direct to save for my path not open dialog save path. My friend suggestion using `response.buffer = true;` @KeyurPATEL

Comment: I try using response, It's open the dialog save path but not open my file in xlWorkBook. @KeyurPATEL

Comment: Try this method: [How to prompt user to save an automated Excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19735906/6741868). If that doesn't work, try the other answers on that page.

Comment: from answer @VBAQueen what  the attribute for myFilename? I don't understand. Where my content `XlFileFormat` to be replace to?@KeyurPATEL

Comment: Adapted to your case, try `object myFilename = xlApp.GetSaveAsFilename(); xlWorkBook.SaveAs (Filename: myFilename);` (Replacing your existing `SaveAs` line)

Comment: Yes worth it. How to set content type to excel file and give the name of filename? @KeyurPATEL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135138/discussion-between-stfvns-and-keyur-patel).

Answer (score 1):

Use below mentioned code for displaying saveAs dialogue box in aspx.

```
        var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(true);

        // to add a sheet to workbook
        AddExcelSheet(dataTable1, workbook, "Sheet Name");

        string spreadsheetName = "DefaultFilename";
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Dialog saveAsDialog = excel.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs];

        // to show dialog box with default filename
        saveAsDialog.Show(spreadsheetName);

        workbook.Close(true);
        excel.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```